# Wordpress - Childtheme language Translation

Tags: wordpress, localization, themes, translation

I'm really really stuck here so I'd appreciate some help from above...

I'm using the jkreativ theme and am currently trying to translate my child-theme.

I am using this code in my childthemes functions.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Setup My Child Theme's textdomain.
 *
 * Declare textdomain for this child theme.
 * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
 */
function my_child_theme_setup() {
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'jkreativ-child', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
?>
```

In my Childthemes Folder I have a folder called "languages" that contains the
de_DE.mo
de_De.po 
files.

I looked in the wordpress codex and to me this seems to be the proper way.
But no single line gets translated...

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks! 
Paul

Answer (score 1):

There is a post at [wordpress.stackoverflow.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185999/override-parent-theme-translation-on-child-theme) with this problem. Basically what you have to do is

1. Create a folder inside your `languages` one with the name of your parent theme;
2. Place there the `.mo` file that will overwrite the parent theme translations;
3. Change your code like this:

   ```
   function my_child_theme_setup() {
       load_theme_textdomain( 'jkreativ', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages/jkreativ' );
       load_child_theme_textdomain( 'jkreativ-child', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
   }
   add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
   ```

   Calling `load_theme_textdomain` and passing the parent theme domain will do the trick.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. The idea with the extra folder inside the languages folder of wordpress is at least something new I can try.
It didn't work (yet) though.
I have the feeling, that the parent theme is missing some information on the textdomain. shouldn't the path to the textdomain be included in the header of style.css of the parent theme?


/*
Theme Name: Jkreativ
Version: 2.3.6
Theme URI: http://themeforest.net
Description: Jkreativ.
Author: Jegtheme
Author URI: http://jegtheme.com/
License: GNU General Public License v2.0
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/